# Constructor finishes by throwing an exception ? Is there a memory leak?

Tags: c++, exception, memory-leaks, constructor

I was going over [this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions#ctors-can-throw) article
 and it states

> Note: if a constructor finishes by throwing an exception, the memory
>   associated with the object itself is cleaned up — there is no memory
>   leak. For example:

```
void f()
{
X x; // If X::X() throws, the memory for x itself will not leak
Y* p = new Y(); // If Y::Y() throws, the memory for *p itself will not leak
}
```

I am having difficulty understanding this and would appreciate it if someone could clarify this. I tried the following example which shows that incase of an exception inside a constructor the destructor would not be called.

```
struct someObject
{
    someObject()
    {
      f = new foo();    
      throw 12;
    }
    ~someObject()
    {
        std::cout << "Destructor of someobject called";
    }

    foo* f;
};

class foo
{
public:
    foo()
    {
            g = new glue();
            someObject a;
    }
    ~foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Destructor of foo";
    }
 private:
  glue* g;
};


int main()
{
    try
    {
        foo a;
    }
    catch(int a)
    {
        //Exception caught. foo destructor not called and someobject destrucotr not called.
       //Memory leak of glue and foo objects
    }
}
```

How would I fix this issue ?

Sorry for the inconvenience the update might have caused.

Comment: The destructors are not called because the objects have never been properly constructed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"... the destructor would not be called."*

Since the object isn't considered as constructed yet, after the constructor failed with an exception, the destructor won't be called.

Object allocation, and construction (merely destruction) are different things.

Any objects allocated using `new()` before the exception is thrown will leak.

> You shouldn't manage these resources yourself, unless you're really, really, really need it, and are about 100% sure about what you're doing.

Rather use suitable smart pointers for class members from the [standard dynamic memory management library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).

Comment: but wouldnt there be a memory leak of glue and foo objects

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Again sorry for the inconvenience the update might have caused.

Answer (score 3):

When the constructor throws, no destructor will be called. When an
 exception is thrown inside a constructor there are several things that
 you should take note of in terms of properly handling resource
 allocations that may have occured in the aborted construction of the
 object:

- the destructor for the object being constructed will not be called.
- destructors for member objects contained in that object's class will    be called
- the memory for the object that was being constructed will be freed.

Comment: Welcome to community! You are using quote markup and link to current question in your answer. Probably both link and quoting are not needed. You may edit your answer via link "edit" under your answer.

Comment: It should be clarified that destructors for class members are called only for members that were fully constructed prior to the exception being thrown. Members that are allocated using `new` inside the constructor body must be `delete`d manually as their destructors will not be called automatically. That means catching the exception, freeing the memory, and then rethrowing the exception.  Or using a smart wrapper to hold the allocated memory until the constructor is ready to exit gracefully.